# 5x1 subplots next to each other - why do I always have the first two that are disappearing?

Tags: matlab, plot, position, subplot

This should be simple - but it appears not. I just would like to have a figure with five subplots next to each other - without spaces in between. Also, the first tricky part perhaps is that I want to have a first subplot that uses floatAxisX.

Let's say I have four variables:

```
 x1 = salinity 
 x2 = temperature
 x3 = density 
 y = depth
```

So my code looks like this:

```
figure;
hfig = figure('Name','xxx');
set(gcf,'Position',get(0,'ScreenSize'))
set(hfig,'color','w');

subplot(151);set(subplot(151),'Position',[0.15 0.15 0.15 0.75]);

    % plot salinity vs depth
     hl1=plot(x1,y,'k-');
    % assign current axis handle to variable for later reference if needed
     ax1=gca;
    % set properties of the axes
     set(ax1,'XMinorTick','on','ydir','reverse', 'ytick',[0:25:150],'box','on','xcolor',get(hl1,'color'))   

    % add 1st floating axis for the second parameter (temperature) plotted
      [hl2,ax2,ax3] = floatAxisX(x2,y,'r:','Temperature (C)',[5 15 0 150]);
      set(ax2,'ydir','reverse','ytick',[0:25:150])

     % add 2nd floating axis for the third parameter (density) plotted
      [hl3,ax4,ax5] = floatAxisX(x3,y,'b--','Density (Kg m^-^3)',[24 27 0 150]);
      set(ax4,'ydir','reverse','ytick',[0:25:150]);

 subplot(152);set(subplot(152),'Position',[0.31 0.35 0.15 0.55]);
```

For example, I have distinct plots put together using `hold on`:

```
        plot(x1,y);axis ij; 

 subplot(153);set(subplot(153),'Position',[0.46 0.35 0.15 0.55]);

        plot(x1,y);axis ij; 

 subplot(154);set(subplot(154),'Position',[0.61 0.35 0.15 0.55]);

        plot(x1,y);axis ij; 

 subplot(155);set(subplot(155),'Position',[0.76 0.35 0.15 0.55]);

        plot(x1,y);axis ij;
```

Note that just doing the following

```
 subplot(151);set(subplot(151),'Position',[0.15 0.15 0.15 0.75]);
 subplot(152);set(subplot(152),'Position',[0.31 0.35 0.15 0.55]);
 subplot(153);set(subplot(153),'Position',[0.46 0.35 0.15 0.55]);
 subplot(154);set(subplot(154),'Position',[0.61 0.35 0.15 0.55]);
 subplot(155);set(subplot(155),'Position',[0.76 0.35 0.15 0.55]);
```

only gives me a figure with the last three subplots next to each other. I would be grateful to get some explanation why this happens and how to solve it.

Comment: I think your real question is about the last few lines of code, which concisely demonstrates your problem. I'm not sure all of the rest helps at all - your question could be shortened.

Comment: I'm not sure if its exactly what you're looking for, but you might check out the [`plotmatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotmatrix.html) function. It's specific to scatter plots, and has other features you may not want. But, I think that it's included with all Matlab installs. Look at the examples. And try `x = randn(50,5); y = 1:50; plotmatrix(x,y','-')`;

Comment: Did my answer end up [solving your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Comment: yes - writing directly under this form helped for sure! thanks and sorry not mentioning it before but yeah that did solve my issue!! thanks a lot! I understood also a bit better these handles which is good ;-)

Comment: I meant that form 'subplot('Position',[0.15 0.15 0.15 0.75]);'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help for `subplot`:

> If a subplot specification causes a new axes to overlap an
> existing axes, the existing axes is deleted - unless the position
> of the new and existing axes are identical.

Your code is doing this, though you may not realize it. You call `subplot(151)`, which places an axis in the default location and then you position it manually. Because you have manually positioned the first axis, calling `subplot(152)` is the same as calling `subplot(151)` and the new axis ends up on top of the first one causing the latter to be deleted. And so on, until you move axes away from the the area where the default axis is placed.

There are several ways around this. You can create all of your subplots and then go back and position them. You can create your subplots starting from the right of your figure (`subplot(155)`) and move left. Or you can create the subplots in the desired positions directly via:

```
subplot('Position',[0.15 0.15 0.15 0.75]);
subplot('Position',[0.31 0.35 0.15 0.55]);
subplot('Position',[0.46 0.35 0.15 0.55]);
subplot('Position',[0.61 0.35 0.15 0.55]);
subplot('Position',[0.76 0.35 0.15 0.55]);
```

You can have these return handles if you need to plot to these axes separately at a later time via `plot(AX,...)` or `subplot(AX); plot(...)`, where `AX` is an axis handle.

Also note that the help for `subplot` contains special comments for the `subplot(151)` style, particularly:

> This syntax does not return a handle, so it is an error to specify a return argument.

I get a handle back myself, but I don't know if it's to be trusted. Still, even changing the style to `subplot(1,5,1)` the issue of only showing the last three persists.

Comment: Ok - thanks a lot - I am still not understanding these handles properly I think..